# Translate information of two dictionaries into a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I believe this is not so easy to explain with words but with an example it should be pretty clear.

Suppose I have the dictionaries `link_vars` and `y`:

```
link_vars = {'v1':'AAA', 'v2':'BBB', 'v3':'CCC'}
y = {'v1':[1,2,3], 'v2':[4,5,6], 'v3':[7,8,9]}
```

And I want to build the list `desired_output`:

```
desired_output = [{'AAA':1 , 'BBB':4, 'CCC':7},
                  {'AAA':2 , 'BBB':5, 'CCC':8},
                  {'AAA':3 , 'BBB':6, 'CCC':9}]
```

So, basically, I want to 'translate' the keys in `y` according to the entries of the dictionary `link_vars`, and then split the lists in `y` into small dictionaries to build `desired_output`. The keys of `y` and `link_vars` will always be the same, and the length of each list in the values of `y` will be the same as well (i.e. there will not be a list with 4 elements and another one with 5).

I'm not being able to think of a smart way to do this. I hope there is an efficient way to do this, as the length of the output list (which is the same as the lengths of each list in the values of `y`) can be pretty large.

Comment: Hint: use `zip(..)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I always forget about `zip()` function (Python newbie here). Thanks! I think I've figured it out now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok fine then. A list comprehension should do in this case:

```
output = [dict(zip(link_vars.values(),i)) for i in zip(*y.values())]
print(output)
```

Returns:

```
[{'AAA': 1, 'BBB': 4, 'CCC': 7},
 {'AAA': 2, 'BBB': 5, 'CCC': 8},
 {'AAA': 3, 'BBB': 6, 'CCC': 9}]
```

---

Taking in consideration jpps comment, maybe a more appropriate approach would be to first make sure that we get the right values by merging the dicts together.

```
temp_d = {v:y.get(k) for k,v in link_vars.items()}
output = [dict(zip(temp_d.keys(),i)) for i in zip(*temp_d.values())]
```

---

Or using pandas library, might be overkill, but the syntax is easy to understand as we only need to merge the dicts and handle the rest with `to_dict()` func.

```
import pandas as pd
output = pd.DataFrame({v:y.get(k) for k,v in link_vars.items()}).to_dict('r')
```

---

**Explanation**

The key idea here is to zip together the values of y. This is done with `zip(*y.values())`. And running the list comprehension: `[i for i in zip(*y.values())]` which equals `[(7, 4, 1), (8, 5, 2), (9, 6, 3)]` the remaining part is to zip together each component with `AAA,BBB,CCC`.

Comment: I didn't understand the problem with the first approach. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @Tendero Since we access values from two different dicts by the values() function we lose the connection to the keys. Meaning that if our dicts are unordered (or that v3 follows v1 instead of v2) we break the order. It's therefore safer to merge the dictionaries first. Printing (temp_d) should explain it.

Comment: @AntonvBR, Looks better now!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution which links the two dictionaries:

```
from operator import itemgetter

keys = itemgetter(*y)(link_vars)
res = [dict(zip(keys, v)) for v in zip(*y.values())]

[{'AAA': 1, 'BBB': 4, 'CCC': 7},
 {'AAA': 2, 'BBB': 5, 'CCC': 8},
 {'AAA': 3, 'BBB': 6, 'CCC': 9}]
```

**Explanation**

1. First, define `keys`, which extracts values from `link_vars` in an order which is *consistent* with the keys from `y`.
2. Second, use a list comprehension and `zip` the pre-calculated `keys` with a transposed version of `y.values()`. We assume `y.values()` iterates consistently with `y.keys()`, which is true in Python 2.x and 3.x.